# unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist

Tags: kubernetes

I have a error when i want to access to my pod:

**error: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist**

it's a cluster with 3 nodes, below some details. Thanks in advance

```sh
root@kubm:~/deploy/nginx# kubectl get nodes -o wide

NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME

kubm       Ready    master   37h   v1.17.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-150-generic   docker://19.3.5

kubnode    Ready    <none>   37h   v1.17.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-150-generic   docker://19.3.5

kubnode2   Ready    <none>   37h   v1.17.0   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.4.0-150-generic   docker://19.3.5

root@kubm:~/deploy/nginx# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES

nginx-59c9f8dff-v7dvg   1/1     Running   0          16h   10.244.2.3   kubnode2   <none>           <none>

root@kubm:~/deploy/nginx# kubectl exec -it nginx-59c9f8dff-v7dvg -- /bin/bash

**error: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist**
```

Comment: Can you format the question using `code` block to make it readable, plz ?

Comment: In my environemnt i am able to connect perfectly to the nginx pod with no issue same command ````ubuntu@cluster-master:~$ kubectl exec -it nginx -- /bin/bash


root@nginx:/# date
Tue Jan  7 14:27:57 UTC 2020
````

Comment: Kube Api Server logs?

Comment: Can you connect to your pod when you are on the same node ?

Comment: What CNI plugin are you running? Can you list what pods are  in Kube-system namespace?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error on my cluster where i do not wait for the container in the pod to be ready and fire a exec command .. but once the pod is ready the exec command works perfectly fine toward container

````ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never
------------------------
pod/nginx created
-----------------------

````ubuntu@dlv-k8s-cluster-master:~$ kubectl exec -it nginx -- /bin/bash
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("nginx")````

**Can you confirm if you are able to reproduce the issue consistently**

Comment: @D.T I reproduce the issue consistently.

Comment: I can to access into the container with docker exe **docker exec -it 6b50237afc6b /bin/bash**

Comment: I can see that all your nodes have to same ip address. This is not correct. Can you list your system pods using `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` . What`s your environment? Did you created this cluster using `kubeadm`? Where are you running those machines?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue running a cluster with `Vagrant` and `Virtualbox` the first time.

Adding `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is your VM's IP in `/etc/default/kubelet` (this can be part of the provisioning script for example) and then restarting kubelet (`systemctl restart kubelet`) fixes the issues.

This is the recommended way to add extra runtime arguments to `kubelet` as you can see in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`. Alternatively you can also edit the `kubelet` config file under `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was POD status as "ImagePullBackOff". Due to this, it was throwing error

```
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("nginx")
```

```
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-598b589c46-zcr5d   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          116s
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$
[mayur@mayur_cloudtest ~]$ kubectl exec -it nginx-598b589c46-zcr5d -- /bin/bash
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("nginx")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `10.0.2.15` IP address is the default for `virtualbox` `NAT`

If you deploy a `VM` using a `vagrantfile`, your `eth0` adapter will use the `10.0.2.15` IP address and the `eth1` adapter will be assigned an other IP address.

`K8s` uses the `eth0` adapter to route packets between pods.

Answer (score -3):

I use below command to get into a pod.

```
kubectl exec -i -t <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

**Note** `-i` and `-t` flag have a space on the command..

If you have multi-container pod you should pass container name with -c flag or it will by default connect to first container in POD.

```
ubuntu@cluster-master:~$ kubectl exec -i -t nginx -- /bin/bash
root@nginx:/# whoami
root
root@nginx:/# date
Tue Jan  7 14:12:29 UTC 2020
root@nginx:/#
```

**Refer help section of command** `kubectl exec --help`

Comment: As already pointed by @acid_fuji can you confirm your cluster bringup step are correct or not .. master and worker node all are pointing to same ip ... can you try to bringup a new nginx pod on master by using toleration for taint on your master node .. find it using >> ````$ kubectl describe node kubm | grep -i taint
```` should result someting like Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule .... then just for test **add toleration** to new-pod at creation time so it lands on master node and check if you can open interactive exec session to it or still same issue..